# How to launch another app or bring it back to foreground like Android launcher?

Tags: android

I am developing two apps that will be installed on the same device. My customer wants a shortcut button on each to jump to the other app in its current state. This action would duplicate the behavior of pressing HOME then pressing the other app's launcher icon. If the app has not been started, it would start it. If the app has already been started, then the current activity is resumed. Each app has many activities, so the current activity at the top of each app's task stack would be unknown at run-time. I have searched all over and have not found this problem answer sufficiently. I have tried variations on this code without success:

```
    Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I am at a loss, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out my problem. Here is what works:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example", "com.example.MyActivity"));
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```